# WP All Import is skipping all Woocommerce Products rather than creating new ones

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I friend of mine has a website which uses WP All Import to import/update/delete woocommerce products. I'm offering some help with the SEO but the import element really has me struggling.

Unfortunately, it has recently stopped creating new products and only updates or deletes them.

I believe it is because of a PHP filter in the function part of the plugin:

```
<?php
function my_is_post_to_create($xml_node, $import_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    
    $productNameNode = $xml_node['product_name'];
    
    if ($xml_node['merchant_name'] == "Test Merchant")
    {
        $productNameNode = $xml_node['product_name'];
    }
    
    $query = "SELECT `post_title` FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts` WHERE `post_title` = '" . $productNameNode . "'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
    return ( empty( $results ) ) ? true : false;
}

add_filter('wp_all_import_is_post_to_create', 'my_is_post_to_create', 10, 2);

?>
```

I'm awful with PHP so if anyone can spot a reason as to why the products are being skipped in the import I'd be very appreciative.

EDIT: I managed to get it working by changing the 'FALSE' to 'TRUE' but that's just a temporary fix so I can get the products imported. As mentioned in the comments, I understand that it is checking for duplicate product names but it's not working correctly.

Comment: Tried this - https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/ ?

Comment: The problem may be due to the fact that you are trying to import products with the same name as an existing product. In this case, the import of the product is skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the replys. @Vdgaetano - Yeah, I see that the PHP works that way but it doesn't make sense that in a new import of 15,000 products, they all already exist on the website.

Comment: In step 4 of the import you could insert as "Unique ID" the couple "product name" + "product sku". However, it is best to ask WP All Import support directly.